# Disable context menu on right mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm developing an asp.net project, I want to disable context menu that appears on a right mouse click. On the master page I wrote this code:

```
<body dir="rtl" oncontextmenu="return false;"></body>
```

the context menu is disabled on all pages but it is enabled on `iframe`. I dont want the user to be able to save or inspect  `iframe` content.
Any idea?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274338/is-it-possible-to-disable-right-click-on-an-iframe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The iframe does also have a body element. Just set the same 'oncontextmenu' there.

Comment: I did that and it didnt work.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });`