# Make Image not copyable

Tags: html, css, image, browser

I am developing an E-Commerce website on ASP.Net and I have a lot of product images in that.Now what i want is i don't want people to right click on my images and copy or save it on their system.I know if the user is determined he can make a copy of my images like taking a screenshot or other things like it,but i don't care it.For me i just not want people to come and take my pictures as easy as it is now.  Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: No. Watermark the images if you want to, but if you display the image to the user, they *will* be able to make a copy, if they're determined enough.

Comment: As soon as it shows on screen you pretty much can't do much. In worst case the user can take a screen shot - in my opinion preventing user to save images is just a waste of money on a developer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client wants "uncopyable images" on website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840761/client-wants-uncopyable-images-on-website)

Comment: the asp.net tag should be removed as this is a client side problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prevent users from right clicking your images. But the user will still be able to make a copy if they really want it. The best solution would be a watermark I think.

You can prevent users from right clicking images by adding `onContextMenu="return false;"` to your image code.

See http://www.pagetutor.com/no_right_click/index.html for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If your really determined on getting this result and don't want to use watermarks, you could

use divs and set it's background image to the intended image.

This won't give viewers the "save image as" option on right click. However they can still work their way around.

I'd personally not recommend using this method as it's really a waste of time, and could be problematic when making changes in the future. However if you REALLY need this done and can't adopt watermarked images (which I'd rather recommend) you could go for this workaround.

Comment: -1 ? This technique is sucessfully used by flickr. Also it prevents the "right click menu".

Answer (score 0):

Images shown on a user screen is - at least - downloaded and stored in a temporary folder on the client side, so there is no way to avoid people saving it. The least you could do is watermark your images (but there are plenty of solutions to un-watermark them, on top of being most of the time unpleasant on your pages), the best you could do is to make your images useless or irrelevant outside of your website...

Answer (score 0):

make transparent div and cover it on top of image element to prevent it