# How to avoid Menu items having navigate Url property with #

Tags: asp.net, contextmenu, menuitem, navigateurl

I'm binding some items to a menu. Assuming, my site address is "www.abc.com/Dev", the menu items automatically get the navigateUrl of "www.abc.com/Dev/#".

Now, these menu items when clicked open some applications like 'Notepad'.

Because of the navigateUrl property of these menu items, if I right click on the items, it gives me a context menu and if I click on 'Open in New Window', it takes me back to my original site.

Ideally, this is the wrong behaviour. 
Is there some way I can prevent the setting of the navigateUrl? I tried making:

```
menuItem.NavigateUrl = null
```

But once the menuItems are initialized, they have the navigateUrl property set with #.

Is there any way I can prevent this.

Comment: menuItem.NavigateUrl = string.empty have you tried this?

Comment: I'd tried 
    menuItem.NavigateUrl = string.Empty
and 
    menuItem.NavigateUrl = ""...
But they both set the navigateUrl to '#" once its rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well do the following in that case,

put menuItem.NavigateUrl = string.Empty or menuItem.NavigateUrl = "" which will produce "#"

On the top of that add menuItem.attributes.add("onclick","TrackRightClickAndReturnFalse")

This way you can have "#" but you can prevent the right click button click on it...

See this [How to disable right-click context-menu in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript) to see how you can get idea on how to disable right click.

I hope you understand my concept.

Comment: Thanks Jigar Pandya,
I tried this:
    menuItem.Attributes.Add("onContextMenu","return false;");
This essentially prevents the context menu from appearing.
Thanks once again. :)

Comment: I would love to do that. But I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow and I dont have enough reputation points to do that. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
menuItem.NavigateUrl = "javascript: void(0);";
```

Comment: This prevents the navigation from happening. But unfortunately, it disables the default left click behaviour. The menu item does nothing once it is clicked. :(