# Joomla 1.5 How to hide my website source code?

Tags: jquery, xcode, joomla, obfuscation

how can I hide my website's source code from users? 
Example is here (we can't click right mouse button): 
http://www.internetine-tv.narod.ru/

Or if it is immposible maybe can I hide part of code? If i want to hide my embed TV channel's code, can I do that? for now everyone can find It in source code.
Thank you for answers.

Comment: I can still get the source code by hitting ctrl U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to disable the context menu, take a look at this Q already on SO - [How to disable right-click context-menu in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript)

Put it like this, any information you send to the browser, like an embed code, will be viewable by the user. There aint much you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The best you can do is obfuscate it. In Chrome for example, on the site you gave I can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view the source.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the (x)html, css or javascript source code.
you can hide your python/php/asp code (just don't allow directory walking)
If you are using php or asp (or a different server side language - ie python) you can make it nasty to view and hide some of it - ie all your php code to generate your page doesn't show which you can have if you want to obfuscate the code add junk data which is a nasty thing to do but is the closest thing you can do to hide your html code.
HTH