# How can i hide my platform (CMS)

Tags: drupal, joomla, drupal-7, joomla2.5, meta-tags

I have Joomla and Drupal sites, but I don't want others to find out what platform (CMS) I'm running.
I want to prevent detection from tools like Wappalyzer or similar tools. (as seen in this screenshot: http://i43.tinypic.com/2evc6qo.png)

I've heard that has to do with meta tags but I'm not sure.

Comment: remove favicon image ...:-) based on your attached image am saying this..anyway viewsource will tell its joomla or drupal is it??   http://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-hide-the-fact-that-youre-using-wordpress/

Comment: Well, I'm sure that you could determine what the extensions are checking and thwart that, overall you are probably just wasting your time. Make sure the CMS stays up to date and running the latest version and you will be doing pretty much all you need to do.

Comment: Completely pointless exercise - spend your time implementing real security instead. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-obscure-the-fact-my-site-uses-drupal

Comment: Well, why would you want to do that? Even if you user gets access to administrator page, s/he will need username/password to get in. Make the username & password strong enough!

Comment: No way you can Hide the platform.
Joomla, wordpress and many more CMS are open source, why do you need to hide the platform when you are using it, As you are using the the open source platform, give some credits to the developers team, instead of hiding the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide the fact you're using Joomla. If you inspect the source code of a websites built using Wordpress for example, you will see **wp-includes** within the URL's of CSS and JS file includes.

When using Joomla, you can type **/administrator** at the end of the URL, however if the admin URL is hidden, against, inspecting the source can give it away.

This might be of little help:

[How to disable right-click context-menu in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript)

Comment: Disabling the context-menu will not prevent detection by Wappalyzer or similar browser plugins

Comment: Well there is nothing else you can do unforrunately

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal, see the community wiki page "[Hide, obscure, or remove clues that a site runs on Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/766404)":

> The short answer is :
>   **You can't. Do not try.**

You can get pretty far with trying to hide the fact that your site runs on Drupal. But at some point you’ll probably don’t run Drupal anymore ;-)

Have a look …

- at our sister site, *Drupal SE*: [How can I obscure the fact my site uses Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-obscure-the-fact-my-site-uses-drupal)
- at *drupalscout.com*: [Hiding the fact your site runs Drupal OR Fingerprinting a Drupal Site](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/hiding-fact-your-site-runs-drupal-or-fingerprinting-drupal-site)

Answer (score 0):

There is way to hide Joomla from bots.

You need to use this [jomdefender](http://www.corephp.com/joomla-products/jomdefender.html) plugin. It removes word joomla from all pages, change admin page and add few antibot tricks.

Its not perfect, but it still adds much more security to your joomla such as file integrity check, which could be quite usefull when some file gets hacked.