# how can I find out what script is causing a page to not allow highlighting of text or right clicking?

Tags: javascript, html

Every time I go to aliexpress with Chrome I find I cannot highlight text on an items page (I can on the search results list though), and I cannot right click to get the context menu on images, for example. both behaviors work just fine in Edge.

The only error I see in the console is two of these:

```
618686_795079156.html?spm=5261.7049941.1998509440.374.8HLhc7&sdom=101.342.433.0_795079156:1 [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'about:blank' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data: *.aliexpress.com *.aliunicorn.com *.alipay.com *.aliyun.com *.alicdn.com *.aliimg.com *.alibaba.com *.alisoft.com *.doubleclick.net *.mmstat.com *.greencompute.org *.video.taobao.com *.itao.com *.tbcdn.cn *.taobaocdn.com *.akamaihd.net *.taobao.com www.google-analytics.com https://stylessl.aliunicorn.com https://assets.alicdn.com https://ynuf.alipay.com https://login.alibaba.com https://login.aliexpress.com *.amap.com *.cnzz.com *.cnzz.net apis.google.com *.googleapis.com translate.google.com www.gstatic.com https://www.google.com bs.yandex.ru mc.yandex.ru vk.com *.vk.me *.facebook.com connect.facebook.net static.criteo.net *.criteo.com". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have an adblocker in chrome but even if I turn it off I still get this behavior. I'd like to correct it, but to do that I have to find out what is wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right click disabling is quite possibly coming from a use of [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which other answers describe as a way to get this behavior; [here's one picked more or less at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985320/disable-contextmenu-and-rightclick-menu).

One way to try to find out which script is causing this would be to use the Chrome web inspector and search in all sources (ctrl+shift-F on windows) for 'preventDefault' and throw a breakpoint on every call to it, then right click on the appropriate element or elements and see if you hit a breakpoint.

Inability to select text may be due to the use of the (non-standards track) CSS property [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).  If you find the element or elements that you cannot select in the Elements tab of the web inspector, you can look at their computed CSS style and see if the `user-select` property is set to `none`.

Comment: these were interesting comments and I voted you up for the detail you added. unfortunately neither lead to anything.. `preventDefault` is not in any content from any `http://aliexpress.com/store/product/`-* page (didn't show up at all with ctl+shift+F from the inspect panel), and `user-select` only exists (as `-webkit-user-select`, etc) in an iframe that is not part of the content at all.

Comment: Very, very curious!  Can you provide a link to one of the product pages on which you see this behavior?  I don't see it in http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Min-order-is-10-mix-2014-Factory-Outlet-elegant-pearl-big-Vintage-Style-Imitate-Collar-Necklaces/811278_850680960.html

Comment: @ ellisbben — huh ... the one you gave is an example of a page that gives me this issue in chrome but not in edge. it is those product pages. Same issue with my ad blocker off. I just checked, even with Incognito mode and all extensions not allowed incognito, it still does it. chrome Version 47.0.2526.58 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: for me it happens everywhere in aliexpress. It works perfect on others sites including alibaba, amazon, gearbest etc...

Comment: I can't find a page which exhibits this behavior on https://aliexpress in chrome beta 69.0.3497.42.  @Kostanos if you find a way to reliably get this behavior, why don't you capture a HAR? https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Content-Troubleshooting/How-to-Generate-a-HAR-File-in-Chrome-IE-Firefox-and-Safari/ta-p/366

Answer (score 1):

The console is saying you have a CSP violation. CSP stands for Content Security Policy and the list shows all of the domains that cannot run JavaScript.

This can be added by your ad-blocker or the website headers. From the sounds of it, the ad-blocker isn't deactivated properly.

Comment: thank you. I disabled my adblocker and the errors went away (replaced with a "connection refused error ... here, if interested: `GET http://atmamos.im.alisoft.com/muliuserstatusx.atc?beginnum=0;8pctgRBMALNEhd…9r8PrPJ8;8pctgRBMALNEhdyYkfatd2gW9r8PrPJ8;8pctgRBMALNEhdyYkfatd2gW9r8PrPJ8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`) — it didn't change the mouse behvior issues but it did fix the console error, so thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. CSP headers are useful, but they can catch you out.