# How did 9gag make pictures uncopiable?

Tags: html, image, copy

So, I always just right-clicked and pressed "save picture" to save a post. But recently they changed something, and I couldn't do anything to a picture without opening source& What could have been changed?

Comment: I just want to know alghorythm used by exact site, not a general solution

Answer (score 2):

[You can disable right-click with javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript)

But in fact you cant stop people from copying.

1. as previously said, view source
2. disabled javascript
3. screenshot

Comment: I am not trying to implement same thing, I want to know how did 9gag make it.

Comment: @RomaValcer Then read the source code!