# Disable save and copy option on the images in IE 11 using CSS

Tags: css

I have used CSS fix in Chrome and Firefox i.e

```
pointer-events: none
```

But pointer-events isn't working on Internet Explorer. Can someone please help me with the IE 11 fix.

Comment: Genuinely curious, why do you want to disable these options? They're generally very convenient for users, and there are other ways to obtain the image (screenshot, go to link url, etc..)

Comment: Can still view source and get image link

Comment: Yes, you are wasting your time. Unless you hash/encrypt these we still have access via Developer Tools

Comment: if you want to do this, then js is probably the better option for disabling the context menu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript

Comment: Have you forgot about Keyboard Short-cuts ? You probably want to handle them as well, a 'Ctrl+s' would save the whole page including the images. not to mention F12 to open the source and get the `Url` directly

Comment: It is actually one of the requirements in my application. There are lots of images which are as part of blogs and got a requirement to disable save/copy options on images.

Comment: Tried 'disabling the context menu' also, but jquery is taking time to load and if I right click on an image before the script executes, i'm able to view the save/copy option(context menu).

Comment: @Divya I realize that you didn't probably create that requirement, you're just following orders, but even if you disable the context menu people can still download and save the images. It's a false sense of security. Maybe you can push back on the requirements?