# Can someone help me make my custom Context Menu position next to my curser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, contextmenu

As said, i'd need some help on my custom context menu, maybe some litle tweeks here and there, or a new idea of how to solve the problem Or a better approach to this problem. (The HTML and CSS sould stay somewhat the same if its possible).

[I don't know, what I should type, but stack overflow said, I should write more because there is so much code, so just ignore this text here in the square brackets.]

HTML:

```
    <!-- ----------------------------------------- [CONTEXT MENU] ----------------------------------------- -->
    <div id="context-menu">
        <div class="item-title" id="context-menu-title">
            <i></i>
            <h1>Schnellwahl:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="context-menu-home" onmouseleave="contextMenuHome_notActive()"
            onmouseenter="contextMenuHome_active()">
            <a href="/index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="context-menu-contact" onmouseleave="contextMenuContact_notActive()"
            onmouseenter="contextMenuContact_active()">
            <a href="/kontakt.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i>Kontakt</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="context-menu-link" onmouseleave="contextMenuLinks_notActive()"
            onmouseenter="contextMenuLinks_active()">
            <a href="/link.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Links</a>
        </div>
        <div id="context-menu-datenschutz" class="item">
            <a id="item-datasafety-lock-open" href="/datenschutz.html"><i
                    class="fa-solid fa-lock-open"></i>Datenschutz</a>
            <a id="item-datasafety-lock-closed" href="/datenschutz.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>Datenschutz</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*--------------- [CONTEXT MENU] ---------------*/

#context-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 150px;
    background: #494949;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: top left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 2.5px;
}

#context-menu h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#context-menu h1::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 145px;
    background-color: #e91e63;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#context-menu.active {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#context-menu .item {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #eee;
}

.item-title {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #eee;
}


#item-datasafety-lock-closed {
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#item-datasafety-lock-open {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#context-menu-datenschutz:hover #item-datasafety-lock-closed {
    display: block;
}

#context-menu-datenschutz:hover #item-datasafety-lock-open {
    display: none;
}

#context-menu .item:hover {
    background: #555;
}

#context-menu .item a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#context-menu .item i {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#context-menu hr {
    margin: 2px;
    border-color: #555;
}
```

JS:

```
//----------------------------------------- [CONTEXT MENU] -----------------------------------------

const hoverContacts = document.getElementById("contextMenuContact")

window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var contextElement = document.getElementById("context-menu");
    contextElement.style.top = event.offsetY + "px";
    contextElement.style.left = event.offsetX + "px";
    contextElement.classList.add("active");
});



window.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.document.getElementById("context-menu").classList.remove("active")
});

function contextMenuHome_active() {
    document.getElementById("context-menu-home").innerHTML = '<a href="/index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-beat" ></i>Home</a>'
}

function contextMenuHome_notActive() {
    document.getElementById("context-menu-home").innerHTML = '<a href="/index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-house" ></i>Home</a>'
}

function contextMenuContact_active() {

    document.getElementById("context-menu-contact").innerHTML = `            <a onmouseout="contextMenuContact_notActive" onmouseover="contextMenuContact_active" href="/kontakt.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-book fa-bounce" style=" --fa-bounce-start-scale-x: 1; --fa-bounce-start-scale-y: 1; --fa-bounce-jump-scale-x: 1; --fa-bounce-jump-scale-y: 1; --fa-bounce-land-scale-x: 1; --fa-bounce-land-scale-y: 1; --fa-bounce-rebound: 0;" ></i>Kontakt</a>`


}

function contextMenuContact_notActive() {


    document.getElementById("context-menu-contact").innerHTML = `            <a onmouseout="contextMenuContact_notActive" onmouseover="contextMenuContact_active" href="/kontakt.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i>Kontakt</a>`

}

function contextMenuLinks_active() {
    document.getElementById("context-menu-link").innerHTML = '<a href="/link.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-link fa-flip"></i>Links</a>'
}

function contextMenuLinks_notActive() {
    document.getElementById("context-menu-link").innerHTML = '<a href="/link.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Links</a>'
}
```

Thank you for your Support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated, try something like this maybe. Just a warning, it's most likely not very compatible across browsers.

See answers: [How to disable right-click context-menu in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript)

```
// html
<body oncontextmenu="handleOnContextMenu()">...</div>

// maybe you can set it on oyur div as well, im not sure to be honest 
<div class="your-div" oncontextmenu="handleOnContextMenu()">...</div>

// js
function openCustomContext(x, y) {
  const yourCtxElement = document.getElementById('ctx-menu')
  yourCtxElement.style.top = y + 'px';
  yourCtxElement.style.left = x + 'px';
}

function handleOnContextMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;

  openCustomContext(x, y)
}
```

Or you could add it like this as a listener:

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 

  // get your X/Y here...
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  openCustomContext(x, y);
}, false);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your Answer, but you are in the wrong section of the code, the code, that you are adressing is just the code, to start the animation. The 

```
<div class="item" id="context-menu-contact" onmouseleave="contextMenuContact_notActive()"
            onmouseenter="contextMenuContact_active()">
```
Is just the command to make it bounce up and down if hovered over the icon

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question is? Your question title says: "Can someone help me make my custom Context Menu position next to my curser?", what other functionality are you after?

Comment: When I rightclick, I want the context menu to pop up next to the curser like if you'd rightclick in your browser (the curser touches the top left side of the context menu).

Comment: Ah, alright, I updated my answer, hope it helps! Gotta go now, so don't expect fast replies :P good luck dude!

Comment: Hmm, I see where your going with that, but it still won't work. Like it won't even open it just does nothing.

EDIT: I see the problem e.preventDefault() isn't defined.

Comment: Says the console

Comment: HEYYY, THANK YOU I just added yourCTXElement.classList.add("active") to the function, and it worked

Comment: Of course, didn't even consider that it was still hidden haha, good job!